# Setting ftdetect a given directory

Tags: autocmd, filetype, netrw, ftdetect

I'm looking for a way to set `filetype` on load, a loading phase via `ftdetect`.

Right now I can open the files inside a given directory via some utility function that I wrote, and during the opening phase, I'm setting a `filetype` and it works.

Now what I want to achieve is that no matter where or how I open something of that kind, I would like to have a `ftdetect` rule, that matches the correct `filetype`.

Let's say I have a variable as `let g:special_dir = '/path/to/dir'`, and that directory has an arbitrarily deep file tree.

I would like that whenever I open `/path/to/dir/deep/route/file`, I set one `filetype`, but If I open `/path/to/dir/deep/route/directory` I set another.

I have being reading, it's not clear to me If I can set a variable to be the *matching* criteria for the `autocommand` that does the setting, but at least if I can parametrize the glob expression that it's used there, I can instead of setting the file type plain and simple, I could call a function that does that.

In other words, I would like to find a way to do something like

```
function SpecialFileTypeResolver(filename)
 " Logic"

endfun
let g:special_dir = '/path/to/dir'

au BufNewFile,BufRead g:special_dir :call SpecialFileTypeResolver(<filename>)
```

Now I know that you can set file type to directories, `netrw` and `nerdtree` do something similar, but honestly I haven't had a deep jump in to the code, I've only tried and `grep` out the file where that condition is coded, but no luck there.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `:execute` to interpolate expressions into the command.

Comment: Here is an example: https://github.com/benknoble/wiki-md/blob/master/ftdetect/wiki.vim If that helps, let me know and I can write up an answer.

Comment: Ok, that worked, but I'm still missing the case on _opening directories_, I thought of adding a rule on `ftplugin/netrw.vim` to check change the `ft`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Ah, opening directories is its own beast; other than using netrw im not familiar with doing anything special for those

Comment: If you check the way [nerdtree](https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree/blob/81f3eaba295b3fceb2d032db57e5eae99ae480f8/plugin/NERD_tree.vim#L155) does that, it has a way to _hijack_ `netrw`, I managed to solve this.

Comment: Clever. Post an answer, if you would